# Does such cryptographic scheme exists?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is there any multi-key additive homomorphic encryption scheme based on elliptic curve cryptography? Meaning adding encrypted values encrypted with different public keys and decrypt the total sum with a private key. The keys are points on an elliptic curve.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure right now what _exactly_ an "multi-key additive homomorphism" is. Would you please mind to [edit] to clarify what property it is that you want exactly (preferably using formulas as to avoid ambiguity)? Also over what group is "addition" to be understood here? Integers modulo a prime? Elliptic Curve Points? ...?

Comment: @SEJPM multi key homomorphic encryption allows requiring multiple decryption keys. Some even allows combining ciphertexts under different keys such that both keys are required to decrypt the result of the computations (similar to MPC protocols)